# Bad text generation results while great prediction results

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Inspired from this [tutorial](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/recurrent-neural-networks-lstm-tutorial-tensorflow/) , I've trained a Bi-directional RNN model, using lstm cells on the PTB dataset (a simple next-word prediction): Given a sequence of 50 timesteps, at each word t predict word t+1. The training is getting accuracy of about 95% accuracy for the train set and the test set is getting about the same accuracy.

Now, I'm trying to generate new text sequence of 50 words - given a starting word I want to predict next word based on previous step's prediction (e.g. the input in cell “t” is the max probability prediction of cell “t-1”).

The generation task brings me very poor results, with almost all repeated words and I'm wondering what goes wrong.

```
def generate(model_path, reversed_dictionary, gen_word_count, predict_full_sentence=True,start_word=0):
    test_input = Input(batch_size=1, num_steps=num_steps, data=test_data)

    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None])
    y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None])

    m = Model(x, y, input=test_input, is_training=False, vocab_size=vocabulary)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        current_state_fw = np.zeros((NUM_LAYERS, 2, 1, HIDDEN_SIZE))
        current_state_bw = np.zeros((NUM_LAYERS, 2, 1, HIDDEN_SIZE))

        # restore the trained model
        saver.restore(sess, model_path)

        sentence = start_word    # 0 is 'the'
        sentence = np.reshape(sentence, (-1, 1))
        for step in range(gen_word_count):
            if predict_full_sentence:
                pred, current_state_fw, current_state_bw = sess.run([m.predict, m.state_fw, m.state_bw],
                                               feed_dict={m.init_state_fw: current_state_fw,
                                                            m.init_state_bw: current_state_bw,
                                                          x: sentence})
            else:

                pred, current_state_fw, current_state_bw = sess.run([m.predict, m.state_fw, m.state_bw],
                                               feed_dict={m.init_state_fw: current_state_fw,
                                                            m.init_state_bw: current_state_bw,
                                                          x: np.reshape(sentence[:,-1], (-1, 1))})
            sentence = np.append(sentence, pred[-1])
            sentence = np.reshape(sentence, (1, -1))
        print(" ".join([reversed_dictionary[x] for x in sentence[0]]))
```

The `predict_full_sentence` flag is for choosing weather I want to predict next word based on the sequence so far, or based just on the sequence's last word (many to one vs one to one)

Here's a sample of generated text:

> the old the old the old the old the old the old the old the old the
>   old the old the old the old the old the old the old the old the old
>   the old the old the old the old the old the old the old the old the